# Extract string and save each in txt

Tags: extract, string

I have a file text with inside :

line1 name1

line2 name2

How can I extract as this?

Extract & copy line1 to a new file saved as name1

Extract & copy line2 to a new file saved as name2

I used space as separator.  I can use any other if it's necessary.

I didn't try anything because I am not a developer.

I'm on PC with Win 10.  I searched software or tool to do this but don't find anything.

From a now deleted "Answer" that should be edit

yes..."foo bar" to a file named baz

info : I don't have other space character than the separator in the file.txt example

Comment: Does `foo bar baz` mean "`foo bar` to a file named `baz`"? or "`foo` to a file named `bar baz`"?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I extract as this?

The easiest way would probably be to write a small script. A simple, native Windows PowerShell example is given below:

*ex. readme.txt*

```
line1 name1

line2 name2
```

*ex. split.ps1*

```
# Read each line in a text file, then write that line to a file with the same
# title as the last word in the line.

# --- Main ---

# Get the contents of readme.txt and place it into a variable.
# $file_contents = Get-Content -Path .\readme.txt

# Visual Aid
Write-Output ''

# Prompt the user for the path to e.g. readme.txt. 
$file_contents = Get-Content -Path (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a file name')

# Read each $line in $file_contents
ForEach($line In $file_contents) {

    # Remove any trailing spaces at the end of the line.
    $line = $line.trim()

    # If the $line isn't blank...
    If($line -NotContains '') {

        # Separate the words in each $line by e.g. spaces. Place them into
        # an array and then get the last word in the array (line). Any final
        # array element can be accessed with -1.

        $last_word = $line.Split(' ')[-1]

        # Write $line to a file with a name based on $last_word.
        Out-File -FilePath .\$last_word.txt -InputObject $line

    }

}

# Visual Aid
Write-Output ''
```

**Usage Examples**

From the command prompt (`cmd`):

```
powershell .\split.ps1
```

From a PowerShell prompt:

```
.\split.ps1
```

Note that in the examples above, `.\` is a path meaning "the current directory". You can also use full paths as well (e.g. `"C:\some\path\to\split.ps1"`).

Be aware that PowerShell may need to have its execution policies changed in order to run scripts. To do this, you need to be an administrator. You can read more about setting execution policies for PowerShell in this [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1).

**Notes**

- The path entered with `Read-Host -Prompt` should either be just the name of the file (assuming e.g. `readme.txt` is in the same directory as e.g. `split.ps1`) or it should be the full path to the file (e.g. `C:\some\path\to\readme.txt`).
- With `Read-Host -Prompt`, using double quotes (`""`) is unnecessary, even for paths with spaces.
- Output files (e.g. `name1.txt`, `name2.txt`) are currently written to the same directory as `split.ps1`.

**Caveats**

- Any output files will be overwritten if the script is run multiple times.
- E.g. `name1` and `name2` are assumed to be single words (i.e. without spaces). If the format was instead `line firstname lastname`, then e.g. `lastname.txt` alone would be the output file name.
- While a small effort is made to ensure file names aren't blank (`$line = $line.trim()`), any other invalid character in e.g. `readme.txt` could (hypothetically) cause issues.

---

*Resources*

- *[Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Write-Output](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Read Host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.1)*
- *[Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1)*
- *[ForEach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1)*
- *[If](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.1)*
- *[Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1)*
- *[NotContains](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/contains/#Example_5:_PowerShell_-NotContains) (non-Microsoft source)*
- *[Arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1)*
- *[Out-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1)*